# How can I send a message only after previous has been responded using Netty?

Tags: java, netty

I have to send a command to the server.

- When server replies OK, I can send the next command, if I have.
- If server replies an error, I have to print it and try again later or stop depends on command.
- If the server does not reply, I have to send the command again after a few seconds.

For example like AT commands.

I know ChannelInboundHandler, but I can't create a complex architecture like this, I don't know how to create the right code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you are using netty for client or server implementation. I had similar use case, and was making use of channel pipeline to achieve the same. Basically, I have one separate handler for `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Response>`, in this handler subsequent request will be sent over channel as well.